# User Profile Service Configuration problem: no update of user information even in full synch

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, profile-sync

I'm encountering some problems with UPS. After the installation every user from sharepoint has all fields parametrized (eg.: Department) but if I change them and launch a Sync (full or incremental) my profile data won't change...

Any suggestion? The profile service synch is configured..

If I take a look to the Logs, when I try to access to the field Department i Receive this exception:

```
An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile.   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileCache.GetUserData(UserProfileManager objManager, Nullable`1 recordId, Guid gAcct, String strAcct, Byte[] bSid, String strEmail, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAccount)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.RetrieveUser(String strAcct, Guid gAcct, Byte[] bSid, Nullable`1 recordId, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAccount, Boolean loadFullProfile)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile..ctor(UserProfileManager objManager, String strAcct, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAccount, Boolean forceUserIsSelf, Boolean loadFullProfile)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.GetUserProfile(String strAccountName, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAcco... 7650f392-b6f2-4496-9533-d3b1e3330cc5
```

If I Take a look at accounts in manage accounts I see only one account even if I have set every account of my domain to be imported.

Any suggestion? I have the same problem in 2 different installation of sharepoint on the same domain network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disinstalling services and reinstalling it following step by step this guide, I won!

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx